# How to use the purpleair.com API

Tags: json, api

When looking at the purpleair.com map we can see markers which show a number. When the API is used this number which is shown on the map is not any of the json values.

Example of map:
https://www.purpleair.com/map?opt=1/mAQI/a10/cC0&select=61037#12.81/37.41523/-122.04362

Example of json:
https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=61037

I assume the number shown on the map can be derived from the json values, but what is the calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Was wondering the same thing. I found a Javascript function that has the formula to calculate the AQI form the PM2_5Value. Don't ask me why it's not in the response.

It's pretty long and mixed together with some other junk, so I'll just leave the link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15ijz94dXJ-YAZLi9iZ_RaBwrZ4KtYeCy08goGBwnbCU/edit

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. I found this link which shows PHP code to get the AQI number.

https://gist.github.com/jasonsnell/7fdb03d3d7dd2b87ed88454b581786d8

Answer (score 0):

Went through the same effort tonight to build a routine to query Purple Air (PA) via MS Excel > Power Query, capture the http response in Parts Per Million of 2.5 um particulate (PM2_5 aka Stats>"v" aka Stats>"pm"), and output as AQI (number and category) following the snippet in the API Doc/Google Doc.

To convert PM2_5 to AQI, PA performs a linear interpretation between breakpoints within the relevant section of the AQI = f(PM2_5) function (there are 8 sections)

1. The 8-section AQI = f(PM2_5) is described at EPA's [AQI Breakpoints](https://aqs.epa.gov/aqsweb/documents/codetables/aqi_breakpoints.html) Reference Table
   -> Each Parameter = *AQI* section is the same and has 8 rows making up the 8 sections.
   -> I built a table in Power Query (Table.FromRecords, fyi) from the left 5 columns
2. Measured PM2_5 defines the section
   -> Low Breakpoint < PM2_5 < High Breakpoint
   -> Can peel off "AQI Category"
3. Linear Interpolation within section
   -> AQI = (High AQI - Low AQI)/(High Breakpoint - Low Breakpoint) * (PM2_5 - Low Breakpoint) + Low AQI
4. I wouldn't get caught up in the highest segment (>501 AQI aka > 500.5 PPM of 2.5um)
   -> Substitute HIGH ALARM for interpolation function

Answer (score 0):

When I called PurpleAir support and asked them for the calculation, they sent me the calculation in the form of an excel VBA custom function. It does seem to work.

Support response below:

The best way to calculate the AQI in Excel is to create a custom function. Click here for a how-to on creating custom functions in Excel.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Below is the VBA code to convert PM2.5 concentrations into PM2.5 AQI. Once you create the function, you should be able to use the function "=pm25toAQI()".

```
Public Function pm25toAQI(pm As Double)
pm = Round(pm, 1)
If pm >= 0 And pm <= 12# Then
aqi = 50 / 12 * (pm - 0) + 0
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
ElseIf pm >= 12.1 And pm <= 35.4 Then
aqi = (100 - 51) / (35.4 - 12.1) * (pm - 12.1) + 51
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
ElseIf pm >= 35.5 And pm <= 55.4 Then
aqi = (150 - 101) / (55.4 - 35.5) * (pm - 35.5) + 101
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
ElseIf pm >= 55.5 And pm <= 150.4 Then
aqi = (200 - 151) / (150.4 - 55.5) * (pm - 55.5) + 151
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
ElseIf pm >= 150.5 And pm <= 250.4 Then
aqi = (300 - 201) / (250.4 - 150.5) * (pm - 150.5) + 201
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
ElseIf pm >= 250.5 And pm <= 350.4 Then
aqi = (400 - 301) / (350.4 - 250.5) * (pm - 250.5) + 301
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
ElseIf pm >= 350.5 And pm <= 500.4 Then
aqi = (500 - 401) / (500.4 - 350.5) * (pm - 350.5) + 401
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
ElseIf pm >= 500.5 And pm <= 99999.9 Then
aqi = (999 - 501) / (99999.9 - 500.5) * (pm - 500.5) + 501
aqi = Round(aqi, 0)
Else
aqi = "NA"
End If


pm25toAQI = aqi


End Function
```